# Can someone decypher whether HP keyboard 608558-XXX is compatible with the new DV7-5000ev?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

It appears that according to this page ..

[http://www.amazon.com/HQRP-compatible-608558-001-605344-001-Replacement/dp/B005G2QZ8I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005G2QZ8I)

.. 608558-001 / 605344-001 / 608559-001 / 593298-001 are compatible,

but according to the manual of the laptop at ..

http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02666747/c02666747.pdf

.. 605344 is the right one.

However, the 608558 does look the same.

Is anyone confident the 608558 and 605344 are compatible? I have found 605344 at a reasonable price.

I currently suspect they are the same or almost the same but HP rebrands them to keep the prices up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was, but it's not exactly the same. e.g. the Return key appears larger which could make part of the cover slightly different. But it's still possible to fit. I do not know if there are differences between regional keyboards but most probably not.